# Python regular ex

Tags: python, regex

I had to do this task with python: select all words in data frame column that do not contain only one or more (lower and upper case) letters, spaces, and periods. 
I tried this piece of code but it tells me that the pattern is incorrect:

```
import re
countries = gapminder['country']
# Pattern that contains all words that do not satisfied the specification
pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z \.]+')
mask = countries.str.contains(pattern)
# Select the complement of mask 
invalid_countries = countries[~mask]
print(invalid_countries)
```

Comment: Did you try `invalid_countries = countries.str.contains(r'^[^a-zA-Z.\s]+$')`?

Comment: Thanks very much @WiktorStribiżew, yes it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
invalid_countries = countries.str.contains(r'^[^a-zA-Z.\s]+$')
```

The regex is `^[^a-zA-Z.\s]+$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^a-zA-Z.\s]+` - 1 or more chars other than letters, `.`, whitespace
- `$` -  end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `contains`, which will look for the pattern anywhere in the string. You probably want `match` instead, with an anchoring pattern (putting `^` at the start and `$` at the end to force the whole string to match).

```
pattern = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z \.]+$')
```

Comment: please take a look at [pd.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), I'm sure that the problem is in the pattern.

Comment: It uses re.search to find the expression within the string. This means that something like “$$$x$$$” would pass the filter because it contains “x”. That’s not what you want.

Comment: I did not get your first answer until @WiktorStribiżew explained it to me, thank you too.